# logback not writing on file

Tags: java, logging, logback, appender

I'm trying to implement logback with the java api, i have an xml configuration that i use by default to log daily and on application startup and then i have the application where i activate/deactivate logging by package name, so i have to start logging when i click the button activate. This is my java method to start logging

```
public boolean startLog(final LogDTO logDTO) {
    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    Date logDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'_'HH-mm-ss");
    String fileName = logDTO.getName() + "_" + formatter.format(logDate) + ".log";
    String filePath = loggingPath + "/console/" + logDTO.getUserId() + "/" + fileName;
    String appenderName = userTools.getCurrentUser().getCurrentUtilisateurId().toString() + "_" + formatter.format(logDate);

    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new RollingFileAppender();
    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setPattern("%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-50.50logger{49} | %-200m |  %-5thread |%C.%M\\(%F:%L\\) %n");
    encoder.setContext(ctx);
    appender.setEncoder(encoder);
    encoder.start();
    appender.setFile(filePath);

    SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> triggeringPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<>();
    triggeringPolicy.setMaxFileSize(FileSize.valueOf("10MB"));
    triggeringPolicy.start();
    appender.setTriggeringPolicy(triggeringPolicy);

    FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
    rollingPolicy.setContext(ctx);
    rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
    rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(10);
    String rollingName = "/log/backup/MyApp-troubleshooting_%i.log.zip";
    rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(rollingName);
    appender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
    rollingPolicy.setParent(appender);
    rollingPolicy.start();
    appender.setName(appenderName);
    appender.setContext(ctx);
    appender.start();

    PatternLayoutEncoder logEncoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    logEncoder.setContext(ctx);
    logEncoder.setPattern("%-12date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n");
    logEncoder.start();

    Logger logger = ctx.getLogger(logDTO.getName());
    logger.setAdditive(false);
    logger.setLevel(logDTO.getLevel());
    logger.addAppender(appender);
```

}

The problem is yes it creates the file but it's not writing anything on the file while i'm navigating through the application, i dont know what i'm missing